# Engine gets hot when driving but not at idle

Tags: troubleshooting

If my radiator cap is lower than the intake manifold and hose, could this be a reason for overheating? Will this make air pockets in the engine since I cannot fill the system totally with coolant?     JG

Comment: How much hotter do you mean @user34300?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! What is the year/make/model/engine of the vehicle in question?

Comment: It was a c 1 corvette with a alum. radiator./ sbc

Answer (score 1):

It got so hot I had to pull over and let it cool. Radiator was full so I' m looking for reasons. Timing was ok,slight kick back on start, and it was a cool day. It is a new rebuild but everything seems OK

Comment: Are you user34300 or user34301 ? Much simpker to have only one identity....

Comment: I do not know! First time to use this,

Answer (score 0):

When we had a vehicle with the radiator cap lower than parts of the system we would jack-up the front of the car (or rear depending) so that the air would come out. Also worked for bleeding some brake systems...

Another trick is to release gently one of the higher-up hose clips while gently pressurising the system with extra coolant - but this takes making bits and pieces...

Comment: That sounds like it would work.